# Variable template partial specialization & aliases in c++14

Tags: c++, c++14, variable-templates

I am trying to convert the following array of bit masks to a more compact version.

```
template < typename T >
constexpr T length_mask[];

template <>
constexpr uint64 length_mask < uint64 >[] = {
  uint64(0)
, ~uint64(0) >> 56
, ~uint64(0) >> 48
, ~uint64(0) >> 40
, ~uint64(0) >> 32
, ~uint64(0) >> 24
, ~uint64(0) >> 16
, ~uint64(0) >> 8
, ~uint64(0) >> 0
};
```

Here is what I have...

```
template < typename T, typename I >
constexpr T length_mask_impl[];

template < typename T, std::size_t... I >
constexpr T length_mask_impl < T, std::index_sequence < I... > >[] = {
  ~T(0), (~T(0) >> ((sizeof(T) - I - 1) * 8))...
};
```

I wanted to further simplify this for the client code, so they don't have to write out std::make_index_sequence.  How can I do that?  I am unable to get the syntax right and not sure if this would work either.

```
template < typename T >
using length_mask < T > = length_mask_impl < T, std::make_index_sequence < sizeof(T) > >;
```

That doesn't compile.  What should the declaration/definition of length_mask be?

Comment: `template<typename T> auto length_mask = ..`

Comment: But ... _why_. You're not going to make it more legible. Nor faster. Infact I'd even step back one bit further and write it `... = { 0x0000'0000'0000'0000UL, 0x0000'0000'0000'000FFUL, ....}` So its blindingly obvious what your masks are. -

Comment: 0x499602D2..  that comes up with the following error on gcc 5.1                                                                                                         
                                                     
error: invalid conversion from ‘const int64_t unsigned*’ to ‘int64_t unsigned’ [-fpermissive]
auto length_mask = length_mask_t < T, std::make_index_sequence < sizeof(T) > >;

Comment: Michael...  just trying to explore what is possible